# not able to connect to python socket server remotely

Tags: python, sockets, networking, network-programming

I am new to socket module of python. First i made client and server and input local ip and it worked fine, now I am trying to make it work with public ip and it doesn't seem to work
Server code:

```
SERVER_IP = "0.0.0.0"  # Listen on all available interfaces
SERVER_PORT = 80

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_socket.bind((SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT))
print(f"Server listening on {SERVER_IP}:{SERVER_PORT}")

server_socket.listen()

client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
print(f"Connection accepted from {client_address}")

data = client_socket.recv(1024)
print(f"Received data: {data.decode()}")

client_socket.sendall(data)

client_socket.close()
server_socket.close()
```

Client code

```
SERVER_IP = "my_public_ip"  # Replace with the actual public IP address
SERVER_PORT = 80

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client_socket.connect((SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT))
print(f"Connected to {SERVER_IP}:{SERVER_PORT}")

message = "Hello, server!"
client_socket.sendall(message.encode())
print(f"Sent data: {message}")


data = client_socket.recv(1024)
print(f"Received echoed data: {data.decode()}")

client_socket.close()
```

server logs:

```
Server listening on 0.0.0.0:80
```

Client logs:

```
Connected to my_public_ip:80
Sent data: Hello, server!
Received echoed data: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'; 
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store
Pragma: no-cache

    <html>
    <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000" link="#2020ff" vlink="#4040cc">
    <h2>400 Bad Request</h2>
Your request has bad syntax or is inherently impossible to satisfy.
<div style="display:none">
<ajax_response_xml_root>
<IF_ERRORSTR>SessionTimeout</IF_ERRORSTR>
<IF_ERRORPARAM>SUCC</IF_ERRORPARAM>
<IF_ERRORTYPE>SUCC</IF_ERRORTYPE>
</ajax_response_xml_root>
<span>Padding so that MSIE deigns to show this error instead of its own canned one.</span>
<span>Padding so that MSIE dei

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Note that I am not showing my public ip for security reasons
I just want to make simple survey that anyone can attempt and the results show up on my PC

I tried chatgpt, other forums but didnt get the answers

Comment: In short: You cannot connect to your external IP address from inside the same network due to missing NAT loopback in your router. What you get here is instead port 80 on the router.